# Camera mount for RPi w/ IR lights?

Tags: camera

I have an RPi camera with IR lights. It looks thus:

https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1hvFVIVXXXXXrXpXXq6xXFXXXd/Raspberry-pi-2-Camrea-Sensitive-infrared-light-Raspberry-Pi-night-vision-camera-compatible-with-Raspberry-Pi.jpg

Is there any way to attach such a camera to a 1/4" camera mount? All of the hardware I see for mounting an RPi camera seems to preclude the option of attaching lights to the side of the camera.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if you could modify https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-camera-mount I would be tempted to find a maker space with a 3D printer TBH

Comment: This has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi.